# "Rich text editor" read only does not work

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, readonly

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. 
I have this input text area that I want it to be read only in A sharePoint site so I wrote a method that select the element by id and makes it read only, it should be simple but yet it does not work for me. 
Here my method:

```
function ReadOnlyRich()
{
  document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_74c26ddd_a3bd_4c7b_877d_6a60c1035973_ctl00_ctl05_ctl15_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField_inplacerte").readOnly = true;
}
```

The code in view source of this element looks like this:

```
<span dir="none">
  <div class='ms-rtestate-field ms-rtefield' style=''>
    <div id='ctl00_m_g_74c26ddd_a3bd_4c7b_877d_6a60c1035973_ctl00_ctl05_ctl15_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField_inplacerte_label' style='display:none'>
     Rich text editor QBIQ no & (Title)
    </div>
    <div class=' ms-rtestate-write ms-rteflags-0' id='ctl00_m_g_74c26ddd_a3bd_4c7b_877d_6a60c1035973_ctl00_ctl05_ctl15_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField_inplacerte' style='min-height:42px' aria-labelledby='ctl00_m_g_74c26ddd_a3bd_4c7b_877d_6a60c1035973_ctl00_ctl05_ctl15_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField_inplacerte_label'  contentEditable='true' >
     <div class="ExternalClass67B0DBE162C14FC89FD1116AA392C2F3">
      000100 (<font color="#001965">R-U: </font><br />123456 (<font color="#001965">R-U: </font>Occupational)<br />654321 (<font color="#001965">R-U: </font>/* QBIQ document&#160;description&#160;not&#160;found&#160;in CM Tool. */)<br />
     </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
<span dir="ltr">
```

Comment: I see no textarea, you use a content editable div - not sure how you  would make that readonly - remove the contentdeditable?  But you need to sort out your code - divs aren't allowed inside spans, font tag is obsolete and should not be used

Comment: Can you use `jQuery` ?

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui I can try

Comment: Try this `$('#yourRichTextId').attr("contenteditable","false");`

Comment: Do you mean I do this: function ReadOnlyRich()
{
$('#ctl00_m_g_74c26ddd_a3bd_4c7b_877d_6a60c1035973_ctl00_ctl05_ctl15_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField_inplacerte').attr("contenteditable","false");
 
}

Comment: Do you need a function? Is there a button that call `ReadOnlyRich()`? If so, yes that's what you have to do.

Comment: you would need to use `prop` and not wrap the false in quotes: `.prop('contenteditable', false );`

Comment: @Pete I can't do that....it is an old sharepoint site that runs on IE8 and therefor it has those old tags

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui I did what you suggested but it does not take effect for some reason, I still see contenteditable= 'true'

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SPUtility](https://github.com/kitmenke/sputility) plugin to make a field readonly or editable.

```
<script>window.SPUtility || document.write('\x3Cscript src="/sites/siteCollection/Style%20Library/Scripts/sputility.min.js" type="text/javascript">\x3C/script>')</script>

<script type="text/javascript">


    $(window).load(function () {

// to make a field read-only 
   SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('Internal_x0020_Name').MakeReadOnly();

// or to make it editable again
    SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('Internal_x0020_Name').MakeEditable();
    }); //close load

</script>
```

Comment: This did not work for me as I'm working in internal environment, mening that I can't  call an external plugin.

Comment: i downloaded the plugin and added in Style Library\Scripts folder and included it in my scripts.. you can see that from the first script line